# Equation of a circle in spherical coordinates

Tags: calculus, spherical-coordinates

What would be the equation of an arbitrary circle rotated along some angle  theta around the X-axis in spherical coordinates? For simplicity we may assume that it is a circle with constant radius r.

It seems like it has something to with having polar coordinates within the latitudinal and longitudinal spherical map. However, I'm not entirely certain.

Comment: By "ring" do you just mean circle? Or a solid object?

Comment: What do you call a ring ? Tilted how ?

Comment: Is this a circle centered on the x-axis such that the radius is perpendicular to the x-axis? Or is it simply centered on the x-axis?

Comment: @TheGreatDuck "This is why I shouldn't listen to people commenting I guess." — The people commenting here are extremely knowledgeable and are trying to understand your specific question so that they can better help you. Your remark comes across as passive-aggressive (at least it does to me), which isn't productive.

Comment: @TheGreatDuck Ah, okay, I see. Thank you for clarifying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

You can start from a circle in the $x-y$ plane centered at the origin that is represented by the parametric equation:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\y\\z
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
r\cos t\\r\sin t\\0
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad 0\le t<2\pi
$$
Now using a matrix that represents an isometry you can transform this circle to  another one rotated in any plane passing thorough the origin, and if you use  translations, you can also change the center of the circle.

As an example, the matrix:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\
0&\cos \theta&\sin \theta\\
0&-\sin \theta&\cos \theta
\end {bmatrix}
$$
represents a rotation of angle $\theta$ around the $x-$axis, and the circle rotated in such a way has equation:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x\\y\\z
\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}
r\cos t\\r\sin t \cos \theta\\-r \sin t \sin \theta
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad 0\le t<2\pi
$$

in the same way you can rotate the circle around any axis of rotation, using the matrix that represents such rotation (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Rotation_matrix_from_axis_and_angle)).

Comment: Your answer greatly helped me. For the purposes of my problem, I rotated the circle in the equatorial plane (a geodesic) using the appropriate angle to get the new, transformed geodesic meeting a certain conditions. Cool trick.